# getting thread number in Multicore Programming using C++

Tags: c++

how to get the thread number executing the loop in OpenMp (openmp.h)?

I'm trying to get the thread no so to optimise the flow of program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to implement this in proper order according to your program flow

```
int i;
#pragma omp parallel
{
    i=omp_get_thread_num();
}
```

thus the thread number of currently executing the block of statement is stored in `i`.

Comment: @ Ishwar .Patil  OK...got it ...I was trying for omp_get_num_thread()..                           it was giving weird result.

Comment: omp_get_num_thread() gives you total number of cores in your system .